# Меню c градиентом с помощью CSS

Tags: css3, css, html

[image]

как вот нарисовать вот такую менюшку

с бордюрами справился
в общем получилась копия этого меню но нету таких вот беловатых линей рядом с бордюром, а так же перехода цвета от рыжего к более красному как на картинке, ну и тень, но ее я сам додумаюсь как намалевать

какие css свойства применить?

[image]

Ну вот то что получилось с помощью css

но как убрать нижнюю белую полоску внутри элемента меню (нижний белый бордюр)?

он добавлен вот таким способом

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #ffffff inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #ffffff inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #ffffff inset;
```

вот только если тень наружная можно несколько стилей применить и тени будут пересекаться

а когда тень внутрянняя то при создании новой тени старая перекрывается

как убрать белую полоску, хрен знает

Comment: схреначил на css вручную

вот только проблема теперь с белой полоской внизу (белым нижнем бордюром) - его не должно быть, как убрать?

Comment: сделал с помощью 3-х span у которых абсолютная позиция

хз

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать например так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/yd0f78jv/

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #dc3a37;
    border: 1px solid #9b0700;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f74d2d 0%,#dc3a37 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #fff;
}
.test:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #dc3a37;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе некоторые зацепки:

CSS Gradient - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

CSS - before и after, box-shadow и border.

Так же есть плагин для Photohop - а для перевода фигуры со стилями в css формат http://css3ps.com/ очень удобная штука.

Если есть в psd меню, можно сделать, а с картинки это дурдом.